# Nativescript auth service not logging in

Tags: typescript, authentication, nativescript

I tryed to add an authGuard on Nativescript grocery tutorial.
Basicaly i have a login page and a list page, my app land on list page but, if the user is not logged in (no token), it send you to login page.
The problem is that when i press sign in it does nothing and i get no errors.

this is the AuthGuard:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UserService } from "../shared/user/user.service";
import { Config } from "../config";

@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{
    constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService,) { }

    canActivate() {
        if(Config.token != "") {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the login service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, map, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

import { User } from "./user.model";
import { Config } from "../config";

@Injectable()

export class UserService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    register(user: User) {
        return this.http.post(
            Config.apiUrl + "user/" + Config.appKey,
            JSON.stringify({
                username: user.email,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }),
            { headers: this.getCommonHeaders() }
        ).pipe(
            catchError(this.handleErrors)
        );
    }

    login(user: User) {
        return this.http.post(
            Config.apiUrl + "user/" + Config.appKey + "/login",
            JSON.stringify({
                username: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }),
            { headers: this.getCommonHeaders() }
        ).pipe(
            map(response => response.json()),
            tap(data => {
                Config.token = data._kmd.authtoken;
            }),
            catchError(this.handleErrors)
        );
    }

    getCommonHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.append("Authorization", Config.authHeader);
        return headers;
    }

    handleErrors(error: Response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

this is the router

```
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { ListComponent } from "./list/list.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./shared/authGuard"

export const routes = [
    { path: "", component: ListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent }
];

export const navigatableComponents = [
    LoginComponent,
    ListComponent
];
```

And the app.module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from "nativescript-angular/http";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { NativeScriptUIListViewModule } from "nativescript-ui-listview/angular";
import { AuthGuard } from "./shared/authGuard"
import { UserService } from "./shared/user/user.service";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { routes, navigatableComponents } from "./app.routing";

@NgModule({
  providers: [ 
    AuthGuard,
    UserService
  ],
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NativeScriptUIListViewModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...navigatableComponents
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Anyone know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not navigating the user to your desired route after a successful login. `CanActivate` only executed when you navigated to a route with `canActivate` guard, which is in your case the `ListComponent`. Hope it answers your question mate. You can use `router.navigate` to navigate to a route.